# How can I optimize this code that I wrote to make an accordion?

Tags: javascript

dear friends, I am just learning javascript and I wrote a code to make an accordion, but I feel that there are much better ways to implement this accordion, I would be grateful if you could guide me with the methods Get to know better.
This is the code I wrote:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.content')

let activeTarget;
for (let i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("click",
        (event) => {
            if (contents[i].classList.value === "content open") {
                contents[i].classList.remove('open')
            }
            else if (activeTarget !== undefined) {
                activeTarget.classList.remove('open')
                contents[i].classList.add('open')
                activeTarget = contents[i]
            } else {
                contents[i].classList.add('open')
                activeTarget = contents[i];
            }
        }
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the `else if` and `else` into just one `else`, then check if `activeTarget` is `undefined` in the new `else`. This reduces duplicated code.

Then let's change the condition in the `if` to use `contains` instead. This will be safer, because you don't check if the class list is *exactly* `content open`. Instead you only test if the element has the `open` class.

```js
if (contents[i].classList.contains("open")) {
    contents[i].classList.remove('open')
} else {
    if (activeTarget !== undefined)
        activeTarget.classList.remove('open')
    contents[i].classList.add('open')
    activeTarget = contents[i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than IF statements, you can just preemptively remove the 'open' class from all, then reapply it for the activeTarget. I did add an IF statement to allow the user to close an accordion item by clicking on it again.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.content')
let activeTarget;

contents.forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", e => {
  contents.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('open'));
  if (activeTarget == e.target) {
     activeTarget = null;
     return;
  }
  activeTarget = e.target;
  activeTarget.classList.add('open');
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be:

```js
// one click listener for the document rather than for every element
document.addEventListener((e) => {
  // if the user clicks on inputs
  if (e.currentTarget.tagName === 'input') {
    // input & accordion items are bound with the data-id attribute,
    // make sure elements have data-id attributes with the right values
    const current = document.querySelector(`.content[data-id="${e.currentTarget.dataset.id}"]`)
    // remove "open" class for every accordion item
    document.querySelectorAll('.content').forEach((item) => {
      item.classList.remove('open');
    });
    // toggle "open" class on the accordion item
    current.classList.toggle('open');
  }
});
```

Feel free to ask questions about the code in the comments! Thanks.

Comment: I'd say having one event listener rather than for every accordion item is a huge performance boost.